# Codeigniter: Combining activeRecord with manual queries?

Tags: php, mysql, database, activerecord, codeigniter

I've though a bit about the activerecord vs. manual queries in Codeigniter. ActiveRecord is awesome when it's all about standard queries and holds development  time really low.

However, when there's a need to add some complexity to the queries, the ActiveRecord gets quite complicated to work with. Sub queries or complex joins gives atleast me a lot of headache.

Since the current "$this->db->query" -call immediately executes the set query, it can't be combined with normal activeRecord calls.

So, what can I do to combine the two methods?

Example of what I want to accomplish:

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$this->db->manual('UNION'); // My own idea of db-call that appends UNION to the query
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable2');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Thanks!

Comment: show us un example of a complex query and maybe we can think about how we could do it using ActiveRecord.  AFAIK you can't combine $this->db->query() + $this->db->get() if this is what you meant.

Comment: Hi, this is actually something that I have been thinking about for some time, so I am afraid that I don't have a specific example right now. As you say, I am aware of $this->db->query() + $this->db->get() cannot be combined :)

Comment: I'm with Bogdan, an example query would be good.

Comment: Hi guys, updated my original post with an example of what I would like to do. It could be a great way of extending the activeRecord feature with more advanced stuff without having to write the whole query from the beginning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this link will help: [active record subqueries](http://shawnmccool.com/2009/09/18/using-code-igniters-active-record-class-to-create-subqueries/)

Update---

there were another discussion about [Union with Codeigniter Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040655/union-with-codeigniters-active-record). And I agree with the answer there.

But with some subqueries we can combine active record with manual queries. Example:

```
// #1 SubQueries no.1 -------------------------------------------

$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$query = $this->db->get();
$subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();

// #2 SubQueries no.2 -------------------------------------------

$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable2');
$query = $this->db->get();
$subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();

// #3 Union with Simple Manual Queries --------------------------

$this->db->query("select * from ($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2) as unionTable");

// #3 (alternative) Union with another Active Record ------------

$this->db->from("($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2)");
$this->db->get();
```

nb: sorry I haven't tested this script, hope it's works and helpfull..

Comment: Hi Bakazero. Thanks for your link. Very appreciated. Please check out my original post. Updated it with an example of what I would like to do.

Comment: Hi! Like your update a lot. Not as clean as I would like it to be though. Upvote! :)

Comment: This does not work (or no longer works).  _compile_select and _reset_select are protected methods.