# Union Activerecord codeigniter framework

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to perform a union in codeigniter. I found this skeleton of code elsewhere:

```
 $this->db->select('title, content, date');
 $this->db->from('mytable');
 $query = $this->db->get();
 $subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();

 $this->db->_reset_select();

 // #2 SubQueries no.2 -------------------------------------------

 $this->db->select('title, content, date');
 $this->db->from('mytable2');
 $query = $this->db->get();
 $subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();

 $this->db->_reset_select();

 // #3 Union with Simple Manual Queries --------------------------

 $this->db->query("select * from ($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2) as unionTable");

 // #3 (alternative) Union with another Active Record ------------

 $this->db->from("($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2)");
 $this->db->get();
```

What is confusing me is say you have a get_where clause in your original sub query, how do you include that? Something like this:

query 1

```
 $this->db->select('Id,title, content, date');
 $this->db->from('mytable');
 $query = $this->db->get_where('Boo', array('Id' => $foo['foo_Id']);
 $subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();
```

query 2

```
  $this->db->select('title, content, date');
  $this->db->from('mytable2');
  $query = $this->db->get_where('Boo', array('Title' => $foo['foo_Title'])
  $subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write them all in one. You do not have to follow that way. Here I write an example:

```
$q = '
 SELECT userid 
 FROM users
 WHERE userid=10
 UNION
 SELECT userid
 FROM users
 WHERE userid=5
';
$result = $this->db->query($q);
return $result;
```

Comment: I've read that doing it that way is not the best way to do it

Comment: This is the simple and clear way to do this. Could you share what you have read?

Comment: Sure , read here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040655/union-query-with-codeigniters-active-record-pattern[/link]

Comment: Yeah, but if you are not working over a huge project that someday you need to convert the whole database to Oracle, MSSQL or some another supported databases systems, then you can use this solution.

Comment: I am currently using MSSQL, problem is by doing it this way my query will be huge, as I am essentially hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

The example you found would be very hard to follow if not well documented; I would caution you against it.

Your other options include:

- Views
- Stored Procedures
- Hardcoding the query

I would recommend hardcoding it, unless you're saving the possibility of switching db engines, as a commenter mentions.

Remember, [Always Use Gloves](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Complicator_0x27_s_Gloves.aspx)