# how to union all this query code in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

"table 1"

```
$this->db->select('referral1.*, client.*, employee.* ');
      $this->db->from('client');
      $this->db->join('referral1', 'client.referral_id = referral1.referral1_id', 'inner' );
      $this->db->join('assign_psychotherapist ', 'assign_psychotherapist.a_referral_id = client.referral_id', 'inner' );
      $this->db->join('employee ', 'assign_psychotherapist.a_psychotherapist_id  = employee.empid', 'inner' );
      $this->db->where("referral_status ='Assigned' OR referral_status ='Accepted' ");
      $this->db->order_by("referral_date", "desc");
```

"table2"

```
 $this->db->select('referral1.*, client.*, volunteer.* ');
      $this->db->from('client');
      $this->db->join('referral1', 'client.referral_id = referral1.referral1_id', 'inner' );
      $this->db->join('assignvolunteer', 'assignvolunteer.Vreferralid = client.referral_id', 'inner' );
      $this->db->join('volunteer', 'assignvolunteer.Vvolunteerid = volunteer.volid', 'inner' );
      $this->db->where("referral_status ='Assigned' OR referral_status ='Accepted' ");
      $this->db->order_by("referral_date", "desc");
```

How can I join the two queries together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
$sql = ("
SELECT * 
FROM (
select r.referral_date,c.lastname,c.middlename,c.firstname,c.gender,r.presenting_problem,e.employee_nickname
from client c
inner join referral1 r
on client.referral_id = referral.referral1_id
inner join assign_psychotherapist ap
on ap.a_referral_id = c.referral_id
inner join employee e
on ap.a_psychotherapist_id = e.empid
where referral_status ='Assigned' OR referral_status ='Accepted'
order by referral_date desc
)
union all
SELECT * FROM 
(
select r.referral_date,c.lastname,c.middlename,c.firstname,c.gender,r.presenting_problem,v.volunteer_nickname
from client c
inner join referral1 r
on c.referral_id = r.referral1_id
inner join assignvolunteer av
on av.Vreferralid = c.referral_id
inner join volunteer v
on v.Vvolunteerid = v.volid
where referral_status ='Assigned' OR referral_status ='Accepted'
order by referral_date desc
)
 ");
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Since Code Igniter does not support UNION in active record as of version 2.2.1,
you can use query strings to achieve the desired result.

Side note: When using `UNION ALL` be sure that the queries being joined contains the same amount and same positioning of columns to achieve what you want..

You can also use table alias to further shorten your query and makes it more organized.

Comment: there's an error "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: ok sorry for that. please check the updated answer, I have used * because I dont know exactly what are the columns that you will use.

Comment: thank you for the effort helping me but still i have an error "duplicate column name"

Comment: you're welcome, :) can  you enumerate all columns for table client, referrall,volunteer and employee??

Comment: volunteer:
volid
volunteer_lastname
volunteer_firstname
volunteer_middlename
volunteer_nickname
birthday
gender
contact
supervisor_id
address
status
language
acct_id

Comment: referral1:
referral1_id
referral_by
referral_by_type
referral_date
visitor
relationship
contact
calledvisited
presenting_problem
doctor_remarks
professional_finding
referral_status
referral_remarks
intake_interview

Comment: client:
client_id
referral_id
lastname
middlename
firstname
nickname
age
gender
home_address
active_language
passive_language
school
grade
class_hours
start_date
end_date
client_status

Comment: employee:
empid
acct_id
lname
fname
mname
cnumber
position
status
birthdate
gender
address
language
employee_nickname

Comment: ok that would be too many. what are the columns that you will need on your query anyway? you should take note that duplicate column names are now allowed.

Comment: referral1.referral_date, client.lastname client.middlename client.firstname, client.gender, referral1.presenting_problem, employee.employee_nickname or volunteer.volunteer_nickname only this 6 columns

Comment: ok I have updated my answer, note: I only added the columns of your choice.

Comment: sorry for the interruption again i'm having trouble with this query. How can get the value using foreach method

model:
function getAllReferrals(){ $sql = ("query") $this->db->query($sql); }

controller:
$data['referrals'] = $this->all_referral_model->getAllReferrals();
$this->load->view('admin_views/all_referrals_view', $data);

view:
<?php foreach($referrals as $referral): ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

im having this error: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT assessment_topic.id AS NIRUPAM, assessment_topic.name, assessment_update.* FROM
    assessment_topic
    LEFT JOIN assessment_update ON assessment_topic.id = assessment_update.assess_id
    UNION
    SELECT assessment_topic.id, assessment_topic.name, '', 9, '', '', ''
      FROM assessment_topic
) A
WHERE A.school_id = 9
GROUP BY A.name
LIMIT 8
```

// 9 dynamic id pass and 8 dynamic limit pass

Answer (score -1):

A much better answer can be found here - [write union query in codeigniter style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978532/write-union-query-in-codeigniter-style) in short use get_compiled_select() and create your own query.