# php codeigniter select query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

This is the my original SQL query

```
select 'car' as type,id,title,status from car_product
union
select 'van' as type,id,title,status from van_product
```

Now I want to run this query using CodeIgniter, so I try to use this one

```
$this -> db -> select('`car` As type,id,title,status');
$this -> db -> from('car_product');
$this -> db -> where('status =',$status);
$query_car = $this -> db -> get()->result();

$this -> db -> select('`van` As type,id,title,status');
$this -> db -> from('van_product');
$this -> db -> where('status =',$status);
$query_van = $this -> db -> get()->result();

return array_merge($query_car, $query_van);
```

but it's not working, please can you help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040655/union-query-with-codeigniters-active-record-pattern

Comment: "union" is not a problem, problem is "'car' as type" part , it's not supporting in select query , Other thing is i don't want to use "$this->db->query" this one

Comment: Can you please write the error message and print out the `$this->db->last_query()`

Comment: this is the error msg , Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'car' in 'field list'

SELECT `car` As type, `id`, `title`, `date`, `status` FROM (`car_product`) WHERE `status` = 'P'

Filename: C:\wamp\www\admin\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: Read the error. There isn't any column named `car` in your table.

Comment: use this `$this -> db -> select('car type,id,title,status');` and `$this -> db -> select('van type,id,title,status');`

Comment: hi  Shaiful Islam , this also not working

Comment: Hi  Parag Tyagi , yes there is no 'car' column, please check my  original sql query then you can find my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ->query() method directly without using queryBuilder for this.

```
$query = $this->db->query("select 'car' as type,id,title,status from car_product union    select 'van' as type,id,title,status from van_product");
```

Then you can deal it as you deal with your other queries

e.g:

```
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it the active record way, use this one.

```
 $this -> db -> select('"car" type,id,title,status',false);
 $this -> db -> from('car_product');
 $this -> db -> where('status =',$status);
 $query_car = $this -> db -> get()->result();

 $this -> db -> select('"van" type,id,title,status',false);
 $this -> db -> from('van_product');
 $this -> db -> where('status =',$status);
 $query_van = $this -> db -> get()->result();

 return array_merge($query_car, $query_van);
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

$this->db->select(); has an optional second parameter that enables you to use compound select statement when needed.

Note: you will not be protected against backticks when you set the optional parameter to "false"

Comment: @ChamaraMaduranga Accept the answer (green tick left to answer) if the answer helped. It'll close the question and help others for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing '=', :

ex:
$status = 'Chamara'

```
$this->db->where("status",$status);
```

//Produces: WHERE 'status' = 'Chamara'

Suggest: You can use arrays. Maybe in future you'll need to set more than one condition

```
$condition = array("status"=>$status);
$this->db->where($condition);
```

Suggest 2:
Use $this->db->get('van_product'); 
instead of

```
$this -> db -> from('van_product');
$query_van = $this -> db -> get()->result();
```

// Produces: SELECT * FROM van_product

Comment: thanks Deusmar , but my actual issue is                                               `    $this -> db -> select('`car` As type,id,title,status');
     $this -> db -> from('car_product');
     $this -> db -> where('status =','P');
     $query_car = $this -> db -> get()->result();`  codeignator didn't support `'`car` As type`