# How to write union in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
select ID,Name_of_Movie as Name_of_Moviee 
from moviestable 
UNION 
select ID,New_Name 
from moviestable
```

I need this query in codeigniter..

Comment: tried the same but no use..

Comment: show your code.

Comment: you missing } of if.

Comment: no it was there..might be not copied it

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040655/union-query-with-codeigniters-active-record-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are two way for **UNION** first in below

```
$data['values']=$this->db->query(
'select ID,Name_of_Movie as Name_of_Moviee from moviestable       
 UNION  
select ID,New_Name from moviestable')->get()->result_array();
```

> Second way to UNION in

```
$this->db->select("ID,Name_of_Movie as Name_of_Moviee");
$this->db->from("moviestable");
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); // It resets the query just like a get()

$this->db->select("ID,New_Name");
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->from("moviestable");
$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 

$data['values'] = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2)->result();
```

You are implement any one for your query

Comment: Dear Your answer like a comment. please explain it and correct the syntax.. Its very important for stackoverflow guys.